# Where is the hidden cut scene in Bit Trip Beat?

Tags: achievements, bit-trip-beat

According to the list of achievements on Steam, there's a hidden cut scene. Where is it?

The achievement is called 'Beginning', which might be some kind of hint!

[image: Beginning]

Comment: I am guessing that it has something to do with the menu screen, cause if you launch a bunch of menu... ball... things... and miss em with your paddle it starts making odd noises. I never kept it up long enough for one reason or another, so I don't know for sure... But without running and looking it up, that would be my guess.

Comment: @Aeo, cool idea, I'll have a play :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hidden cutscene is accessed by watching through the credits after the final level.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks.  Not very 'hidden' then :)  I had hoped there was a cool glitch (think Mario minus world) or something.  Thanks for answering.